# How to display two texts in a column using bootstrap?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to understand how to use the bootstrap code in angular but I can't get the columns to work.

I want to display two columns next to one another but I can't get it to work.

I was told to wrap the div's with a container div but that does not work either.

here is the code::

```
<!-- attempt 1 -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:red ;">
      column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:green">
      column 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- attempt 2 -->
<hr>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:yellow ;">
      column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:brown">
      column 2
    </div>
</div>
```

this is what it looks like ::

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using bootstrap 5, xs is no longer available,

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/

if you want 2 columns for all view port widths then use

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:red ;">column 1</div>
    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:green">column 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```